# Unix Client and Server Stuck in an Infinite Loop After Reading a File to the Client

Tags: unix, client

I am currently making a simple client and server but I have run into an issue. Part of the system is for the client to query about a local file on the server. The contents of that file must be then sent to the client. I am able to send all the text within a file to the client however it seems to be stuck in the read loop on the client. Below are the code spits for both the client and server that are meant to deal with this:

**Client Code That Reads The Loop**

```
 else if(strcmp(commandCopy, get) == 0)
        {

            char *ptr;
            int total = 0;
            char *arguments[1024];
            char copy[2000];
            char * temp;
            int rc;

            strcpy(copy, command);

            ptr = strtok(copy," ");

            while (ptr != NULL)
            {
                temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(ptr));
                temp = ptr;
                arguments[total] = temp;
                total++;
                ptr = strtok (NULL, " ");
            }

            if(total == 4)
            {
                if (strcmp(arguments[2], "-f") == 0)
                {
                    printf("1111111111111");
                    send(sockfd, command, sizeof(command), 0 );
                    printf("sent %s\n", command);
                    memset(&command, '\0', sizeof(command));

                    cc = recv(sockfd, command, 2000, 0);
                    if (cc == 0)
                    {
                        exit(0);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Here");
                    strcpy(command, "a");
                    send(sockfd, command, sizeof(command), 0 );
                    printf("sent %s\n", command);
                    memset(&command, '\0', sizeof(command));

                    cc = recv(sockfd, command, 2000, 0);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                send(sockfd, command, sizeof(command), 0 );
                printf("sent %s\n", command);
                memset(&command, '\0', sizeof(command));

                while ((rc = read(sockfd, command, 1000)) > 0) 
                {
                    printf("%s", command);
                }

                if (rc)
                    perror("read");
            }



        }
```

**Server Code That Reads the File**

```
char* getRequest(char buf[], int fd)
{

    char * ptr;
    char results[1000];
    int total = 0;
    char *arguments[1024]; 
    char data[100];

    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    ptr = strtok(buf," ");

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        char * temp; 
        temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(ptr));
        temp = ptr;
        arguments[total] = temp;
        total++;
        ptr = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    if(total < 2)
    {
        strcpy(results, "Invaild Arguments \n");
        return results;
    }

    if(pFile != NULL)
    {
        while(fgets(results, sizeof(results), pFile) != NULL)
        {
            //fputs(mystring, fd);
            write(fd,results,strlen(results));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid File or Address \n");
    }
    fclose(pFile);
    return "End of File \0";
}
```

**Server Code to execute the command**

```
else if(strcmp(command, "get") == 0)
{
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid ==-1) 
    {
        printf("Failed To Fork...\n");
        return-1;
    }
    if (pid !=0)
    {
       wait(NULL);

    }
    else
    {

       char* temp;
       temp = getRequest(buf, newsockfd);

       strcpy(buf, temp);

       send(newsockfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0 );
       exit(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not make the code simpler by first sending the size of the file (in binary)? Then you can just do one read or at least know what you should be expecting.

Comment: why not 'instrument' your code to emit debugging/trace information so you can see exactly which block is causing the problem. Then it should be easy to figure out why it is happening. Also, if you're certain that it's "the client read" that is causing the loop, confirm that by eliminating the server from the picture, by commenting out the socket stuff, if it finishes, then it's something about your handling of sockets, and if continues in infinite loop, then you need to look at how you're reading your file. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The whole `else if` clause in the client code is a bit large for a function, let alone a part of a function as it presumably is.  The logic in the code is ... interesting.  Let us dissect the first section:

```
else if (strcmp(commandCopy, get) == 0)
{
    char *ptr;
    int total = 0;
    char *arguments[1024];
    char *temp;

    ptr = strtok(copy, " ");

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(ptr));
        temp = ptr;
        arguments[total] = temp;
        total++;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
```

I've removed immaterial declarations and some code.  The use of `strtok()` is fine in context, but the memory allocation is leaky.  You allocate enough space for a character pointer, and then copy the pointer from `strtok()` over the only pointer to the allocated space (thus leaking it).  Then the pointer is copied to `arguments[total]`.  The code could, therefore, be simplified to:

```
else if (strcmp(commandCopy, get) == 0)
{
    char *ptr;
    int total = 0;
    char *arguments[1024];

    ptr = strtok(copy, " ");

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        arguments[total++] = ptr;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
```

Nominally, there should be a check that you don't overflow the `arguments` list, but since the original limits the string to 2000 characters, you can't have more than 1000 arguments (all single characters separated by single spaces).

What you have works - it achieves the same assignment the long way around, but it leaks memory prodigiously.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be that the server sends all the contents, but it doesn't close the socket, so the client has no way of knowing the server's done.  If you close the socket after you finish sending the data (or just call shutdown()), then the client's read() will return 0 when it finishes reading the data.

FWIW, there are lots of other problems with this code:

- getRequest: you call malloc but never free.  In fact, the return value is thrown away.
- Why bother forking if you're just going to wait() on the child?
- You probably want to use strlcpy instead of strpcy to avoid buffer overruns.